# React JS Return random 4-6-4 pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am new to react JS. how do I re-format my random into 4-6-4  (numbers and A-Z only)

Required:
On click of Submit, generate an Access Code (random generated)

Here is my code: (We don't want to include any special characters and format the code into 4-6-4)

```js
var randomstring = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-14);
console.log('random', randomstring)
```

random output: 0.214tqeu72fb

We want something like: 1X2X-3X4X6X-7X9X

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own custom function which takes random values from your array of input and generate the random pattern.

```js
const uppercase = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
const lowercase = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
const numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
const alphabets = [...uppercase, ...lowercase];

const getIndex = length => Math.floor(Math.random() * length);

const getRandom = (length) => Array(14).fill(0)
  .map((_, i) => i % 2 ? alphabets[getIndex(alphabets.length)] : numbers[getIndex(numbers.length)]);
console.log(getRandom(14).join('').replace(/(.{4})(.{6})(.{4})/,"$1-$2-$3"));
```